# How to test the value of a CSS selector using Capybara and RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

The HTML page is supposed to have the following code:

```
<div class="user-image" style="background-image:url(/images/user_image.jpg)">
```

How would you check for this using Capybara and RSpec?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Presumably, you are trying to verify that this div uses the specified background image. I would probably do something like this:

```
it "has a user image" do
  page.should have_selector('div.user-image')
end

it "displays the user image" do
  page.find('div.user-image')['style'].should == 'background-image:url(/images/user_image.jpg)'
end
```

RSpec, however, is likely the wrong tool for the job. Consider using Cucumber for tests like this.

Answer (score 4):

Capybara and Selenium allow to run javascript in the browser and return the result

here is how:

```
page.execute_script 'return $("div.user-image").css("background-image");'
```